# Difference in execution time for same code

Tags: time, build, runtime

I wrote the basic Hello world code in C++.

I then built and ran it using CodeBlocks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World!";
}
```

I then did "Build and run" successively many times (doing nothing else on the system meanwhile) and each time the execution time was different. Why is this?

Comment: This is a *very* broad question. There are so many factors to take in account other than your code. The short answer is probably the way your OS handles its resources is different during each run

Comment: Can you please give me some examples of things that changed during each run?

Comment: For example, maybe you have other processes that require CPU. Because your code is very short it's very probable that during some runs it receives more CPU time, which makes it run faster